# Creating a custom maven test report

Tags: maven, selenium, junit, test-reporting

I am trying to create a custom test report using Maven as my build tool, JUnit as my framework, along with selenium test cases. I was using maven's surefire report plugin but I need to include more information in my report. Can anyone direct me to a good tutorial on how to create a custom maven reporting tool?

Comment: You can use allure reporting tool plugin to maven

Comment: Please refer this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31462784/allure-environment-file-in-target-folder-gets-deleted-on-maven-clean-how-do-i

Comment: I recommend [Extent Reports](http://extentreports.com/)

Answer (score 0):

We have a much better test automation dashboard based on just few api calls, ARES dashboard (built under Testastra and owned by ZenQ) is a much better option to try and it's absolutely free.

ARES, is an acronym for Test Automation Results dashboard. It's a TestAutomation framework/tool agonistic solution, that simplifies the collection of Test automation results and their analysis via live dashboard, daily/weekly trends, frequent failures etc. Website: http://www.testastra.com/#ares

Below repo has some code samples, documentation and usage of ARES test automation dashboard:https://github.com/testastra/ARES

Give it a try.

Comment: Below are some of the features of ARES:                                                                              1. Tool agnostic test automation dashboard
2. SaaS based
3. Shows current live execution and historical test automation insights
4. Free for all